# How do companies spot when a person is violating their terms and conditions?

Tags: creative-commons, enforcement, terms-of-service

I'm a developer (startup) and I'm working in a few healthcare projects, I prefer [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) for data visualization.

My questions are as follows:

**1.** Why does one purchase a license when one can use Highcharts for free?

**2.** I will be one among 1,000,000 people using Highcharts, so how does Highcharts (company) spot me as a person violating their laws/terms of service?

Comment: this question is not about free/open source software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a free version of Highcharts](https://shop.highsoft.com/faq#Non-Commercial-0), but it primarily pertains to personal (non-commercial) use.  The most obvious answer to your first question is: **because it's the law**.  Highcharts licenses their software for certain entities to use, so without obtaining the necessary license, you would be in violation of the applicable law.  (I'm not a lawyer, so don't take this as legal advice.)

As for your second question, *if* you used their software without the correct license, they would probably only find out if someone informed them.  The license requires neither a key nor activation, so there's no real registering of your usage of it.

I would strongly recommend purchasing the necessary license, rather than trying to use the software illegally for free.  The "High-five License" is a very affordable option, but being a startup, if you [contact their sales team](https://shop.highsoft.com/contact), they may be able to work with you on pricing.